# Windows Phone 7: List of api-features

Tags: silverlight, api, windows-phone-7, xna

Im searching for a good resource/list of all features I have at my disposal as a a WP7-developer such as music, sound, accelerometer, gps, flashlight, vibrator etc etc. What can I do with the phone? What can I use? Preferable with simple code-examples. Both when it comes to XNA and Silverlight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Windows Phone Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff402535(VS.92).aspx) on the MSDN Library is a great resource for all of the available APIs and with code samples for most of it.

You might also be interested in the following resources:

- [Charles Petzold: Programming Windows Phone 7](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/)
- [Rob Miles: Windows Phone Programming in C#](http://www.robmiles.com/journal/2011/1/5/windows-phone-blue-book-pdf.html)
- [UI Design and Interaction Guide for Windows Phone 7](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=183218)
- [Nick Randolph and Christoper Fairburn: Professional Windows Phone 7 Application Development: Building Applications and Games Using Visual Studio, Silverlight, and XNA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470891661)

Answer (score 1):

As it relates to XNA, you can see all of the educational catalog content that relates to the windows phone platform on the AppHub site at this URL:
http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/?contenttype=0&devarea=0&platform=54&sort=1

Answer (score 0):

Try "Programming with Windows Phone 7" by Charles Petzold:

http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/

It is a free online book that describes the features of WIndows Phne 7 in depth (including the phones hardware capabilities), and how to program in Silverlght and XNA.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff covers alot of features in 31 days of WP7:
http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/post/31-Days-of-Windows-Phone-7.aspx